# fibre of a morphism equal to projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that for projection morphism of schemes $f: \mathbb{P^r}\times S\to S$ and $ s \in S$ the fibre of $f^{-1}(s)$ is $ \mathbb{P^r}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}^r$?  Over what base?

Comment: suppose all scheme over complex number

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will get "a projective space", but with the caveat that if by $s\in S$ you mean *any* point in the topological space underlying $S$ - not necessarily a $k$-valued one - then you have to be accurate regarding the base field of the projective space you obtain, as Eric already mentioned.

First, we have to be explicit on what $f^{-1}(s)$ means *as a scheme*: it's the base change of $f$ along $k(s)\to S$, where $k(s)$ is the residue field of $k$. Now $f: {\mathbb P}_k^r\times_k S\to S$ is, by definition, the base change of ${\mathbb P}_k^r\to k$ along $S\to k$, so by transitivity $f^{-1}(s)$ is the base change of ${\mathbb P}_k^r\to k$ along $k(s)\to k$, which is ${\mathbb P}_{k(s)}^r\to k(s)$.

In particular, if $s$ is a $k$-valued point, then $f^{-1}(s)\cong {\mathbb P}_k^r$ again.

Comment: by $k$ you mean $Spec(k)$?

Comment: @David: Yes, I tend to omit the $\text{Spec}$ usually.

Comment: And if I understand you said that the fibre of $s$ is equal to ${\mathbb P}_k^r\times Spec(k(s))$ over $Spec(k)$. am i right?

Comment: @David: Yes, I'd say that's the _definition_ of the fibre as a scheme, and it's a _proposition_ that on the level of sets, it's indeed the preimage of $s$.

Comment: But sorry one more thing.for $k$ valued point $s$ we get ${\mathbb P}_k^r$.but if i am not wrong in general we have ${\mathbb P}_{k(s)}^r$ not ${\mathbb P}_k^r$.

Comment: @David: Yes exactly, that's also what I wrote.

Comment: So in general the statement that i wrote was wrong.It is just for $k$ valued points?

Comment: @David: You didn't specify the base field, so the question was not well-defined. If you meant $k$ implicitly as the base of projective space then yes you were wrong if $s$ is not $k$-valued.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @David: You're welcome - if things are clear, please accept and close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68228/discussion-between-david-and-hanno).

Comment: @David Is everything clear by now? If yes, could you accept?